# Storing and displaying emojis with mysqldb and Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, encoding, emoji

I have a database with a table called `posts` and I have two fields called `title` and `description`. Both `title` and `description` can contain emoji characters.

The solutions to similar problems told me to `convert the character set to utf8mb4` and `collate to utf8mb4_bin` and also change the column type from `text` to `NVARCHAR(255)`. I've even tried different combinations of using `utf8`, `utf8mb4`, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_general_ci`. They all don't work in displaying emojis.

[image: error]

Instead, this error will pop up once I try displaying the emojis.
Anyone have a work around this?

I tried using different combinations of unicodes and collations to the database, but all don't seem to work.

Comment: `utf8` will not work; all the `utf8mb4` things you tried should have worked.  Please provide `SELECT title, HEX(title) FROM ...` for one of the rows where it is not working.

Comment: @RickJames I used `SELECT title, description, timestamp FROM posts WHERE posts.id=%s;`.

Comment: I need to see the HEX to verify that it was stored correctly.  Meanwhile, `utf8mb4` is required for Emoji.  An incorrect way of "converging" could have mangled the data.  How was the "convert" done?  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had to make sure the `charset connection` and the `collation connection` was set to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` respectively. I did this with the `Flask-MySQLdb` library.

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'host'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'db_name'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
app.config['MYSQL_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'
app.config['MYSQL_COLLATION'] = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

mysql = MySQL(app)
```